# How do i rig this properly (humanoid with fewer limbs)?

Tags: rigging, rigify, mixamo

I'm trying to figure out how to rig this character that i have made.
I have been trying to make it work with Mixamo by converting a rigify rig using Expy Kit.

Unfortunately this causes quite significant deformations in the model, which i'm speculating might be due to the rig having too many unnecessary bones, but it seems like rigify requires all of them.

Any tips on how to go about rigging this character, while ideally allowing me to make use of mixamo animations.

[[image: Metarig]]
[[image: Generated rig]]